# How to detect screen resolution from C++?

Tags: qt

I am trying to detect the current screen resolution (in C++, not in QML) like so:

```
if (QApplication::devicePixelRatio() > 1) {

}
```

But I get the error "call to non-static member function without an object argument" on the first line.

How can I detect the devicePixelRatio() in c++?

Edit: what is the down-voting all about here?

Comment: `qApp->devicePixelRatio()`, which is *not* the screen resolution, but the application-wide fallback default logical to physical pixel ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate `QApplication` first.

You can use the global `qApp` pointer: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#qApp

Or the `instance()` method of QCoreApplication: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#instance

Comment: Thank you, the `qApp` tip was most helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I updated the example. Thank you peppe for your comment/hint.

If you already used Qt 5.x, then use the [QScreen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) class to query screen properties. Such as:

```
#include <QtCore/qdebug.h>
#include <QtGui/qguiapplication.h>
#include <QtGui/qscreen.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   foreach(QScreen *screen, app.screens()) {

      // Query the name
      qDebug() << QString("Name: %1").arg(screen->name());

      // Query the devicePixelRatio
      qDebug() << QString("DevicePixelRatio: %1").arg(screen->devicePixelRatio());

      // Query the Screen resolution
      int nWidth = screen->geometry().width();
      int nHeight = screen->geometry().height();
      qDebug() << QString("Screen-Resolution: %1 x %2").arg(nWidth).arg(nHeight);
   }

   return app.exec();
}


// Output:
// "Name: \\\\.\\DISPLAY1"
// "DevicePixelRatio: 1"
// "Screen-Resolution: 1920 x 1080"
```

Comment: 1) In order to work QScreen obviously requires a QGuiApplication to be created, so that example is faulty. 2) Do *not* create instances of QScreen, ever. Grab it from QGuiApplication via `screens()`.

Comment: Edit is OK. Author is asked for screen resolution, but not for device pixel ratio. Voted up.